# Calling to the owner class from a listener

Tags: java, button, methods, swt, listener

Having the follow class -

```
public class GUIclass1 extends org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite {
    private void initGUI() {

        {
            // The setting of the open file button.
            openButton = new Button(this, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
            openButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent evt) {
                    foo() ; 
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void foo() {
        // implementation ..
    }
}
```

As you can see within the `addSelectionListener` there is a calling to method `foo()`  .

My question is -  which reference I should write as a prefix to `foo()` in order to know which class `foo()` related to .

I tried `super().foo()` with no success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would call it as `GUIclass1.this.foo()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

As we know that `an inner class has an implicit access to the members of the outer class`,
so `this.foo() Will NOT work`, But

`GUIclass1.this.foo() Will WORK`.